# tty - dual monitors

Tags: tty

I have a dual monitor setup running TTY only. The primary monitor is the actual "laptop", and the second monitor (Lilliput um-70) is connected through USB 2.0, using `udl` driver.

Everything is working fine, except for one thing, whenever I change TTY, the old TTY stops refreshing itself.

`tty1` is mapped to `/dev/fb0`, `tty2` is mapped to `/dev/fb1` using kernel parameters during boot (`fbcon=map:01`). When I change to `tty1` (laptop monitor), `tty2` (USB monitor) stops refreshing.

For example, if I put an `htop` on `tty2`, going back to `tty1` to do some stuff, the `htop` on `tty2` freezes. If I go back to `tty2`, it refreshes itself, but `tty1` now stops refreshing.

Any ideas on how to have `tty1` and `tty2` staying refreshed, no matter which TTY is active?

Comment: How do you switch between tty1 and tty2? with ALT+CTRL+F[1-2]?

Comment: Yes. Or cycle using: CTRL+ALT + Arrow.

Comment: Is your parameter `fbcon=map:01`? Because if so, try `fbcon=map:10`,  or even `fbcon=map:1` and then try mapping the consoles with `con2fbmap` afterwards

Comment: Do you mean that this will fix the refreshing problem? I will try it when coming home.

Comment: That is not working.

Comment: By that, do you mean assigning the terminals with `con2fbmap` after the reboot? What do you get when you use `fbset -i` from each console?

Comment: just found a way to do this. I am using yaft as the framebuffer terminal (https://github.com/uobikiemukot/yaft). This framebuffer console allow refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a frambuffer terminal like Yaft (https://github.com/uobikiemukot/yaft).

This needs to be compiled with the config

```
BACKGROUND_DRAW = true
```

in the *conf.h* file.

This allows for refreshing of the VT even if the VTs are inactive. For my specific hardware setup, I had to use the driver "udlfb" and NOT the newer driver "udl".